# 16.04 Nautlius Shift-Del file recovery

Tags: data-recovery, undelete, permanent-delete

The wrong folder was blasted with shift-delete in Nautilus.   I have an older version of the folder, but gap between the two is significant.  This [article indicates that shift-delete is 'permanently' deleted and not in the 'trash](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files-recover.html)':

> If you deleted the file by pressing Shift+Delete , or by using the
> command line, the file has been permanently deleted. Files that have
> been permanently deleted can’t be recovered from the Trash.
>
> There are a number of recovery tools available that are sometimes able
> to recover files that were permanently deleted. These tools are
> generally not very easy to use, however. If you accidentally
> permanently deleted a file, it’s probably best to ask for advice on a
> support forum to see if you can recover it.

## QUESTION

Is there a simple method / tool to recover the folder?

/home/username/blastedFolder

Simple methods are preferred, all suggestions are appreciated: Thank you.  I have some experience using sysrescuecd, however, I am not sure if photorec is the right tool for the job.  There must be a better tool / method!

## Updates

- SSD device: dual boot Windows-10 + 16.04
- Running photorec from sysrecuecd on target partition

Comment: First thing to do is shutdown. Then boot with a live USB and research the Internet from there.